# c# casting child class SOAP

Tags: c#, soap, casting, parent-child

I have a soap Interface with a Method "GetCustomer", which returns a customerDto. I wanted to create a new Interface method for another Client with more infos so I created a second method"GetCustomerExtended" which returns a customerExtendedDto with the customer object as a parent.
To reuse my code I cast the child to the parent, but it seems not working. The soap doesn't return any infos. Here is my code:

soap class:

```
public class ShopService : IShopService
{
    public CustomerDto GetCustomer(int id)
    {
        return GetCustomerExtended(id);
    }

    public CustomerExtendedDto GetCustomerExtended(int id)
    {
        // Fill result
        CustomerExtendedDto result = new CustomerExtendedDto();
        result.Id = 1;
        result.Name = "foo";
        result.Surname = "bar";

        return result;
    }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IShopService
{
        [OperationContract]
        [FaultContract(typeof(InvalidParameterFaultMessage))]
        [FaultContract(typeof(DataNotFoundFaultMessage))]
        [FaultContract(typeof(InvalidOperationFaultMessage))]
        [FaultContract(typeof(ApplicationLogicFaultMessage))]
        [FaultContract(typeof(NotAvailableFaultMessage))]
        [FaultContract(typeof(TimeoutFaultMessage))]
        CustomerDto GetCustomer(int id);

        [OperationContract]
        [FaultContract(typeof(InvalidParameterFaultMessage))]
        [FaultContract(typeof(DataNotFoundFaultMessage))]
        [FaultContract(typeof(InvalidOperationFaultMessage))]
        [FaultContract(typeof(ApplicationLogicFaultMessage))]
        [FaultContract(typeof(NotAvailableFaultMessage))]
        [FaultContract(typeof(TimeoutFaultMessage))]
        CustomerExtendedDto GetCustomerExtended(int id);
}
```

Dto:

```
[DataContract]
public class CustomerDto
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class CustomerExtendedDto : CustomerDto
{
    [DataMember]
    public strint Surname{ get; set; }
}
```

The method seems working and it doesn't throw any expensions, but the answer is always empty. GetCustomerExtended works perfectly fine, GetCustomer is empty. SOAP UI doesn't seems to get any infos. If I fill the customer info in "GetCustomer" like this, it works:

```
public CustomerDto GetCustomer(int id)
{
    // Fill result
    CustomerDto result = new CustomerDto();
    result.Id = 1;
    result.Name = "foo";

    return result;
}
```

What's the problem here? How can I cast here properly?

the SoapUI log says:
Thu Oct 11 11:29:42 CEST 2018:ERROR:Exception in request: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
Thu Oct 11 11:29:42 CEST 2018:ERROR:An error occurred [Connection reset], see error log for details
Thu Oct 11 11:29:42 CEST 2018:INFO:Error getting response for [BasicHttpBinding_IShopService.GetCustomer:Request 1]; java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Comment: Your contract in the GetCustomer method states that it should return the CustomerDto, but you are returning CustomerExtendedDto. This will only return the properties related to the base class.

Comment: getCustomer seems to return nothing. I want the properties of the baseclass. the idea was to reuse my code and don't have two mostly similar methods. But it looks like SOAP has a problem with the casting

Comment: Is this the code which acts as the service? I dont see the `OperationContract` and `ServiceContract` attributes on the method and the class.

Comment: there is an interface with the infos. I added it in the initial post. Currently I'm checking the log of SoapUI and Windows, maybe there are more infos.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, which isn't really nice, but works:

```
    public CustomerDto GetCustomer(int id)
    {
        CustomerDto customer = Mapper.Map<CustomerExtendedDto, CustomerDto>(GetCustomerExtended(id));

        return customer;
    }
```

I think the problem is, that the object is still a "CustomerExtended" object. It's call by reference and I give the customerextended xml back to soap UI(or maybe a mix). With automapper I create a CustomerDto and it works fine.

But I'm still happy for a better solution for this problem.